# Can MongoDB cross datacenter?

Tags: mongodb, couchdb

Question 1:
  As the title goes, Can MongoDB and CouchDB cross data center?

Question 2:
  As I know , MongoDB put more emphasis on performance, thus leading to lower availability and durability.It keep a memory map in memory and lazily persist the data to disk .So ,when a power failure happened, is there a possibility to loss data? And, what about couchDB?

Comment: Yes MongoDB is data center aware, read the documentation on replica sets. MongoDBs availability and durability cna be tuned, again you should reade the documentation

Comment: Also even though CouchDB is ACID in a non-distributed environment it actually uses a asynchronous worker for replication ( http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication ) making it eventually consistent. As such its data loss is no different to MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB replication manual:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/

MongoDB also has something called Journaling which helps provide write durability and crash resilience which as of version 2.0 is enabled by default.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/journaling/

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase (not CouchDB) does provide additional capability through XDCR - cross data center replication the ability to run geographically distributed set of clusters both peer to peer or unidirectional. 
http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-server/architecture